# Delphi Indy: Suddenly experiencing 14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: delphi, openssl, indy10

I have been using

- Delhi XE8 VCL application
- Indy 10.6.2:5263
- OpenSSL 1.0.2k (https://indy.fulgan.com/SSL)
- Windows 10

The following code was working until March 5, 2019

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var URL, SS: string;
    AStream : TMemoryStream;

begin
  URL := 'https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/ESM19';
  SS := 'c:\dump.txt';
  try
    AStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      IdHttp.Get(URL, AStream);
      AStream.SaveToFile(SS);
    finally
      SSL.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
    AStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I now get the error

```
Error connecting with SSL.
error: 149094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert
handshake failure
```

I have since then downloaded the new OpenSSL 1.0.2r. But the error persists. I have also tried every possible combination of the SSLVersions property but the error continues. The error occurs only on certain sites; not all sites.

Any suggestions why the error suddenly started to appear. There have been no changes to my operating environment.

Thanks.

Comment: From indy.fulgan.com/ssl

Comment: @N.Kajiji upgrade to the latest Indy 10.6.2.5495, and see if you still have the same problem. A lot of servers are moving to TLS 1.2 nowadays, but your current version of Indy is missing support for the SNI extension of TLS, which the TLS 1.2 servers usually look for. That support was added in 5321 and 5360.

Comment: Like Remy commented, it looks a lot like a SNI error. Note that, if you can't upgrade to a more recent version of indy (due to time constraint, for exemple) it is possible (maybe not recommended though) to add support for SNI to older version of Indy.  We did so in 5311 by intercepting the call to IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.SSL_set_ex_data and calling IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(vSSLSocket.fSSL, vSSLIOHandler.Host) from there.

Comment: Thank-you, Remy. I am all set. The update to 5495 worked.